# How to export/import object and collection types using expdp - Oracle

Tags: oracle, export, oracle11gr2

I'm trying to export a schema using `expdp` command. All schema objects are imported, except object and collections types. 
Do i need to set specific parameter for this?

```
--Commands
--Export
expdp system/pass@localhost:1521/orcl directory=my_dir schemas = tony_hr
dumpfile=tony_hr.dmp logfile=tpny_hr.log
--Import
impdp system/pass@localhost:1521/orcl directory=my_dir dumpfile=hr_tony.dmp 
logfile=hr_tony_imp.log remap_schema=tony_hr:hr2
```

I simulated the error in a test schema named `tony_hr`. This is a picture of all of its objects:

[image]

The export is executed successful, but when i'm trying to import(using remap_schema to hr2) i get some errors. This is the part where import fails.

```
ORA-39083: Fallo de creación del tipo de objeto TYPE:"HR2"."O_SEAT" con el error:
ORA-02304: literal de identificador de objeto no válido
El sql que falla es:
CREATE EDITIONABLE TYPE "HR2"."O_SEAT"   OID '02C3315E969E44D6BC7D797EDD9F2D96' IS OBJECT
(
    seat_id VARCHAR2 (8 BYTE),
    seat_category_name VARCHAR2 (32 BYTE)
ORA-39083: Fallo de creación del tipo de objeto TYPE:"HR2"."M_SEATS" con el error:
ORA-02304: literal de identificador de objeto no válido
El sql que falla es:
CREATE EDITIONABLE TYPE "HR2"."M_SEATS"   OID '0A71AFB95CCE4CC78558B571199AF83F' IS TABLE OF o_seat;
```

Sorry, because error messages are in spanish. Please ask if you have any doubt.

Comment: which oracle version?

Comment: are you sure the objects and collections are in a schema that was exported?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. I have full access to the schema i'm trying to export.

Comment: It's not about having full access to the schema; are you sure the missing objects aren't in another schema and accessed through a synonym? Can you check `all_objects` for the owner and type based on the names of things you are missing?

Comment: Please, add to the question an exact error message from `impdp` which you got while trying to import `scott.dmp`.

Comment: Is the problem on export or import? If on import, are you using the `REMAP_SCHEMA` option, and are you importing back into the same database? Are there any errors in the export or import logs?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes Alex, problem looks to be on import. I updated the question with the errors i'm giving.

Comment: @ThinkJet i updated the question with import errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use the following parameters in your impdp command, it should import your other collection type objects too,

```
REMAP_SCHEMA=Old_username:New_Username (in case of different schema names )
REMAP_TABLESPACE=Old_tablespace_name:New_tablespace_name ( in case of diff tablespace name)
TRANSFORM=SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES:n
TRANSFORM=OID:n
```